# Ninject kernel suddenly loses all bindings then starts working again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I am using Ninject as dependency injection tool. I have quite big asp.net-mvc 5 project (80 bindings) which, when I step through my code creates the bindings perfectly in the kernel.The NinjectWebCommon.cs. file sporadically failed on the following line of code

```
(kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);)
```

resulting in a new kernel being created and me losing all bindings to my SQL Server database.

```
   private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            AddBindings(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The result is that when I execute the code, I get a NULL model error in the view. The error has corrected itself automagically but I need to know what causes it so that I can rather deal with it. I include the full NinjectWebCommon.cs file

```
using eMedic.Domain.Abstract;
using eMedic.Domain.Concrete;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(eMedic.WebUI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(eMedic.WebUI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace eMedic.WebUI.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                RegisterServices(kernel);
                AddBindings(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void AddBindings(IKernel kernel)
        {
            // add bindings here
            kernel.Bind<IAccountRepository>().To<EFAccountRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IAddressRepository>().To<EFAddressRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IAddressTypeRepository>().To<EFAddressTypeRepository>();

          //other bindings as well (omitted for brevity)
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new eMedic.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }        
    }
}
```

As well as the NinjectDependencyResolver.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ninject;
using eMedic.Domain.Abstract;
using eMedic.Domain.Concrete;

namespace eMedic.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;

        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }


    }
}
```

The data interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eMedic.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IAddressRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<address> Address { get; }

    }
}
```

and the other data interface...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using eMedic.Domain.Abstract;

namespace eMedic.Domain.Concrete
{
   public class EFAddressRepository:IAddressRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        public IEnumerable<address> Address
        {
            get { return context.address; }
        }




    }
}
```

I really would appreciate assistance so that I can get to the root cause of the error.

Comment: What if you do `kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => kernel);` instead?

Comment: Hi Steven thanks for the help, I have figured out what the reason was. Will add it as an answer to my question as reference to other newbies like me :-).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what the problem was and for reference I add the reason here:
I had an error with a foreign key (FK) value in one of the tables I was referencing in my SQL Server database. It had a **NULL** value and when I changed the record to give that specific FK in that specific table a value, the error was cleared.